# Create PKCS12 certificate in JAVA

Tags: java, certificate, pkcs#12

so here's what I'm trying to do:

- I connect to my SSL server
- It sends me two certificates, and one of them is self-signed

At this stage, there are no problems, I've:

```
X509Certificate[] myTwoCerts; 
// with 2 certificates in there, and I'm sure it's there because, I print them in my console.
```

- Now I want to create .p12 file with 2 certificates inside.

Until now, I've tried something like this:

```
KeyStore pkcs12Store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
pkcs12Store.load(null, null);
X509Certificate cert1 = myTwoCerts[0];
X509Certificate cert2 = myTwoCerts[1]
String alias1 = "FIRST";
String alias2 = "SECOND";
pkcs12Store.setCertificateEntry(alias1, cert2);
pkcs12Store.setCertificateEntry(alias2, cert2);
```

But I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported
```

Can anybody help me plz??

Answer (score 1):

The `PKCS12` keystore in Java cannot be used to store certificates or certificate chains without their private keys.

See this note in the [JCA reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeystoreImplementation):

> "pkcs12" is another option. This is a cross platform keystore based on the RSA PKCS12 Personal Information Exchange Syntax Standard. This standard is primarily meant for storing or transporting a user's private keys, certificates, and miscellaneous secrets. As of JDK 6, standards for storing Trusted Certificates in "pkcs12" have not been established yet, and thus "jks" or "jceks" should be used for trusted certificates.

(Despite mentioning JDK 6, this still is in the JDK 7 documentation.)

If you want to store a private key + certificate (chain) in a PKCS#12 store in Java, there needs to be a private key and you need to use the `setKeyEntry` method.

Comment: Although Java 8 (released in Mar '14) and up do support trustedcert, though not necessarily interoperable with other software. And in Java _9_ (in 2017) and up the default storetype is now PKCS12; jks _and_ jceks still work, but keytool warns they are 'proprietary'.

Answer (score 1):

```
keytool -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12   -alias root -genkeypair


KeyStore pkcs12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
String filename = "/tmp/keystore.p12";
keyStore.load(
                    new FileInputStream(/*"myKeyStore.jks"*/filename),
                    password);
```

Comment: This creates a (new) privatekey entry, not trustedcert entries as desired for this question. Also, putting your keystore in /tmp is probably a bad idea.